# Application within same deployment/container behaving differently on different kubernetes clusters

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, ash, on-premises-instances

We are moving applications between different environments/different kubernetes cluster and I have a case where the same shell script is behaving totally different on different kubernetes clusters.

We are running the application on on-premise kubernetes clusters

The issue is with the deployment on new k8s cluster. We have a script node.sh executed in the container like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ash
. ./scripts/functions.sh

source /.env
```

Both scrips node.sh and functions.sh are mounted in the container in /scripts directory as configMaps with defaultMode 0755

In the new cluster I receive errors like "': No such file or directory can't open '/scripts/functions.sh"

If remove the execution of functions.sh it will complain that /.env can't be found and so on

Tried all possible variants like - sh /scripts/functions.sh, #!/usr/bin/env sh, tried different mount directory like / but without success, I receive same kind of error
When running a sleep loop as a command I can execute the container and I can see both of the scripts mounted in the right path  read-only. I execute node.sh but I get same error

Tried to mount both sh scripts on the nodes using hostPath, I get the exact same error

When I try to run the script from inside the container, same issue:

```
/ # ls -la /scripts
total 24
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 May  4 22:26 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May  4 22:26 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           452 May  4 22:26 functions.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          1076 May  4 22:26 node.sh
/ # sh /scripts/node.sh
': No such file or directory can't open '/scripts/functions.sh
```

Older cluster where the script runs without any issue is on kubernetes v1.26.3 and the new one on v1.27.1

Same containerd version same OS and kernel

It's like nothing makes any sense

Does anyone have any idea how is this possible ?